# C# Selenium Button in a Span Class XPath (Amazon.com)

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I am trying to create a proper `XPATH` syntax in `C#` to click on a download button from the Amazon business website.  Everything I have tried is unable to find the button.  Here are some of the things I've tried:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@type='submit']")).Submit();

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(@class,'a-button-inner')][contains(text(),'downloadCSV_button-announce')]")).Submit(); 

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(@class,'a-button-inner')][contains(text(),'Download CSV')]")).Submit();
```

Below is the source code from the Amazon page.  Can anyone help me to design the proper XPATH query to click this download button?  Thank you.

```
<h1>Amazon Business Analytics</h1>
<div class="a-row a-spacing-medium a-grid-vertical-align a-grid-center">
    <div class="a-column a-span12">
        <span class="a-declarative" data-action="aba:download-csv" data-aba:download-csv="{}">
            <span id="downloadCSV_button" class="a-button aok-float-right"><span class="a-button-inner"><input class="a-button-input" type="submit" aria-labelledby="downloadCSV_button-announce"><span id="downloadCSV_button-announce" class="a-button-text" aria-hidden="true">Download CSV</span></span></span>
        </span>
```

[image: Screen shot of Chrome Developer tools]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using [`WebElement#click()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#click--) to perform click on element instead as below :-

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input.a-button-input[aria-labelledby = 'downloadCSV_button-announce']")).Click();
```

Or if `span` element is clickable try as :-

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("downloadCSV_button-announce")).Click();
```

Or

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("downloadCSV_button")).Click();
```

Comment: Your first answer with the CssSelector worked perfectly.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can I ask you a follow up to your answer?  If I wanted to use a wild card when looking for this same tag how could I accomplish that?  Like say instead of looking for 'downloadCSV_button-announce', I instead looked for 'download*' where * does not care what else is on the end.  How would I do that?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could ask another question regarding this, I or someone will give you answer there, thanks..

Comment: Thanks sir.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500248/c-sharp-selenium-loop-through-input-buttons-in-a-span-class-xpath